# how to get service desc from xxx.pb.go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

when I use xxx.proto to generate a golang protobuf file
I see

```
...

var _Auth_serviceDesc = grpc.ServiceDesc{
    ServiceName: "protobuf.Auth",
    HandlerType: (*AuthServer)(nil),
    Methods: []grpc.MethodDesc{
        {
            MethodName: "GenerateToken",
            Handler:    _Auth_GenerateToken_Handler,
        },
    },
    Streams:  []grpc.StreamDesc{},
    Metadata: "auth.proto",
}
```

how can I get the `serviceDesc` out of this package?
I want to get service name and methods

Comment: Seems like you should use https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#Server.GetServiceInfo on the service to get a map from names to `ServiceInfo` instances.

Comment: This used after registered, what I want: if the xxx.pb.go package is 'test', I want to use the test._Auth_serviceDesc.ServiceName to found defined service, not write string

Comment: You'd need to have your test register the service (so that you can retrieve it), or, be in the same package so that you can access the un-exported name `_Auth_serviceDesc`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access the services and methods is via the `FileDescriptorProto` for the proto file(s).  Or, the v2 proto API contains a variable that will contain the descriptor proto in case you don't know the filenames (note that a single proto package may contain multiple files).

Please see https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/489 for more discussion on this topic (and in particular, the last comment by dsnet for how the v2 proto API works in this regard).